# Why is PHP rendering this image incorrect?

Tags: php, png, gd

I try to take an image (.gif, .jpg or .png), and to output it as a .png

This is the code I use:

```
<?php
$filename = urlencode($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);

$size = getimagesize($tempname);

switch($size["mime"]){

    case "image/jpeg":
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tempname); //jpeg file
    break;

    case "image/gif":
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($tempname); //gif file
    break;

    case "image/png":   
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($tempname); //png file
    break;

    default: 
        die('Unknown filetype');
    break;
}

ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

The problem is when I input this, for example:
http://i52.tinypic.com/dzglmu.png

The output becomes this:
http://i53.tinypic.com/15fg8w5.png

Can anyone tell me whats going wrong here?

Comment: The second link says for me `The Image "http://i53.tinypic.com/15fg8w5.png" can not be displayed, because it contains errors.`. Is this what you wanted to show?

Comment: In my browser it shows this: https://img.skitch.com/20110806-xtth8ysmgc2835t81dj75b7xxa.jpg  (This one is a screenshot of the image)

Comment: Sanitize uploaded image data first, don't rely on the mime/type reported by the browser. This information can just be wrong and you then use the wrong function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, it's not really that easy. PNG and GIF carries info about alpha level, which can be lost (and thus rendered in another color). Also, as said by @hakre, mime type provided by browsers is not a really reliable information. And your MIMEs are not complete, as there are other possibilities: as an example, I was having some trouble with IE8 because it assigned the MIME 'image/x-png' instead of the usual 'image/png', and that can easily break your functionality.
A nice reliable way of getting the MIME (and evaluting if an image is really an image, which is an important step to do!) is using [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function

```
$size = getimagesize($file);
$mime = $size['mime'];
```

`getimagesize()` returns an array with 4 indexes, I.E.:

1. The 0 index is the width of the image in pixels.
2. The 1 index is the height of the image in pixels.
3. The 2 index is a flag for the image type:

   > 1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG, 4 = SWF, 5 = PSD, 6 = BMP, 7 = TIFF(orden
   >   de bytes intel), 8 = TIFF(orden de bytes motorola), 9 = JPC, 10 = JP2,
   >   11 = JPX, 12 = JB2, 13 = SWC, 14 = IFF, 15 = WBMP, 16 = XBM.
4. The 3 index contains ' height="yyy" width="xxx" '

I took the afore summary from the manual page I linked, but you can easily test it yourself, I was just being lazy.

You need then at least add for PNGs:

```
imagealphablending($img, true); // setting alpha blending on
imagesavealpha($img, true); // save alphablending setting
```

But look for more complete example on [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) or google up for it, as these were only suggestions, you need to adapt the situation to which extent you need to treat your image.